# How to call an anglesharp async method without AsyncEx library?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, task, anglesharp

With [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/), to load HTML page and wait until all stylesheets are downloaded (if required) and all scripts are ready to be parser executed, I do this

```
    public sealed class WebReader
    {
        private IDocument _ashDocument;

        public async Task Load(string Url)
        {
            var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithJavaScript().WithCss();
            var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
            _ashDocument = await context.OpenAsync(Url);
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> getImage()
        {
            return  _ashDocument.QuerySelectorAll("img").Select(n => n.Attributes["src"].Value);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebReader wReader = new WebReader();           
        AsyncContext.Run((Action)(async () =>
        {
            await wReader.Load("http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/");
        }));
        IEnumerable<string> imageUrls = wReader.getImage();
        foreach (string url in imageUrls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(url);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

AsyncContext is a part of [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) library.

Is it possible to do the same thing without AsyncEx library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do the same thing without AsyncEx library?

Not inside a console application. The whole point of `AsyncContext` is to allow you to await a method in `Main`, which itself isn't async (and can't be). The only alternative is to block the task. Additionaly, as @StephanCleary notes, the continuation inside the context will resume on a single thread, instead of an arbitrary thread pool thread.

Without it, it would simply be:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebReader wReader = new WebReader();           
    wReader.Load("http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/")).Wait();
    IEnumerable<string> imageUrls = wReader.getImage();
    foreach (string url in imageUrls)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(url);
    }
}
```

There are rare cases when blocking with `Task.Wait` is ok, this is one of them.

Side note - Async methods should be marked with the `Async` postfix, hence you should use `LoadAsync`. Also, .NET method naming conventions are Pascal case, not camel case.

Comment: @LeMoussel Yes, it is. Note that this isn't how you'd normally invoke an async method in any environment other than a console app, which is the abnormal case.

Comment: The primary difference between `AsyncContext` and the `Wait` approach is that `AsyncContext` will run all the continuations on a single thread (by default) whereas the `Wait` (in a Console app) will run continuations on the thread pool.

Comment: @StephanCleary I don't think that's a concern here.

Answer (score -2):

Indeed you can:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoWork();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static async void DoWork()
{
    WebReader wReader = new WebReader();           
    await wReader.Load("http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/");
    IEnumerable<string> imageUrls = wReader.getImage();
    foreach (string url in imageUrls)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(url);
    }
}
```

This will do exactly the same, the only difference is the readkey is being executed while the DoWork downloads it's data, if this side effect is not an inconvenient then you're good.

Else, you can use a sync event (ManualResetEvent, AutoResetEvent, etc) to wait until the work has been done.

Comment: Why would you need another `async void` method? `Load` already returns a `Task` which you can block on, removing the need for `Console.ReadKey` completely.

Comment: ReadKey is for waiting user input, to leave the program open until the user presses a key. Also, waiting for Task's usually is a very bad idea, if the task is being executed on the same thread as the Wait caller, it will create a deadlock

Comment: If the OP has a requirement to kill the console app while the operation is still running, than ok, but I don't see the OP mentioning anything in that regards. Regarding your second point, no, it won't deadlock. Console apps use the default `ThreadPoolSynchronizationContext`, where continuations are scheduled on an arbitrary threadpool thread. There won't be any deadlocks here.